# Getting the error #include errors detected. Please update your includePath

Tags: c++

I am getting these errors :

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath  cannot open source file "iostream

I am unsure why. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!";
   return 0;
}
```

I am new to C++ so  tried re writing it to see if there was an issue there, uninstalling and reinstalling the C++ extension on VS Code, it was running before so i have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: A C++ compiler should not be unable to find a standard header. Check that you are in fact invoking the C++ compiler and not a C compiler. There is nothing wrong with the program itself.

Comment: This sounds like you misconfigured IntelliSense, not the compiler itself. If you're on Windows and use MinGW then please read [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). The file you need to update is `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: Here is how the json file looks
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Comment: @MaxineJones Not sure if this is the solution but I would change the `compilerPath` setting to `C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe`. Use g++ for C++ programs and gcc for C programs,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the file contents. It's impossible to format in comments, which make it close to unreadable.